# When do you get access to synthesis?

Tags: the-guided-fate-paradox

I am currently Total Level 100 and Have finished chapter 3. Some shops seem to open up at certain total levels while others unlocked after certain chapters. When do I get access to the synthesis part of the blacksmith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis unlocks by completing chapters.  I believe it unlocks at the beginning of chapter 5.

In the beginning, however, it's not going to be very useful; it only transfers over partial stats, and the number of items you can synthesize into another is very low for the first couple of ranks.  I synthesized a Rank 1 +9 Leg Missile into a Rank 2 Leg Missile, and only got about 4% added to the stats, so it was roughly a 20% transfer rate.  And that was the only item I could synthesize into it.  You're better off not wasting the cash and just focusing on using and strengthening the higher rank items until you start reliably getting Rank 4 or 5 items.

Comment: I just got it and like if you synthesize items with different stats you can get equipment that gives you a lot more bang for your buck.